# Docker run centos6 command fails

Tags: docker

Docker run *centos6* command fails with error :-

```
docker run docker.io/treasureboat/centos6
```

"`docker: Error response from daemon: No command specified`"

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? Maybe the image doesn't set ``CMD``. Did you try ``docker docker.io/treasureboat/centos6 bash``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/treasureboat/centos6/~/dockerfile/) doesn't set a `CMD`, so you need to specify something for docker to execute:

```
docker run docker.io/treasureboat/centos6 /bin/bash
```